# Python deleting row which not contains specific value?

Tags: python-3.x

If the ninth column doesn't contains the name of city ISTANBUL, then I need to be able to delete
the entire row. i wrote the code it works but it doesn't delete row.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

wb = load_workbook('deneme.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

for row in range(1, 3313):
    for col in [9]:
        char = get_column_letter(col)
        if ws[char + str(row)].value is not 'İSTANBUL':
            ws.delete_rows(row)

wb.save('deneme.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is solution i just found.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('staji.xlsx') #here you can put your file path

filt = (df['ŞEHİR'] == 'İSTANBUL') # put your condition ŞEHİR=column name.

df[filt].to_excel('den1.xlsx')
```